# Add HTML5 required attribute to webform fields set as required

Tags: 7, hooks, webforms

Could someone advise me how to use a hook to add the HTML 5 required attribute to all inputs that have been selected as 'required' within webforms.

Webforms already adds class 'required' but the HTML 5 required attribute provides great instant validation in Opera, Firefox and Chrome browsers.

Comment: Do you need a javascript solution or PHP or both ? You can do this by setting form attributes in a hook_form_alter()

Comment: PHP, could you produce an example please?

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a module for this. 
Note that, this answer assumes you need to set required attribute on all form elements which are required in web form settings. 
you will need to implement a different hook and/or add conditions to make this strict.

Create a file named `webform_formalters.info` and put following to it.

```
name = webform form alters
description = a collection of custom form alters for webforms. 
core = 7.x
package = Custom
dependencies[] = webform
```

Create another file named 'webform_formalters.module' and put following in it.

```
<?php
/* 
 * implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter. 
 */
function webform_formalters_form_webform_client_form_alter(&$form){
  //dsm($form);
  foreach ($form['submitted'] as &$field){
   if (is_array($field) && isset($field[#required]) && $field['#required'] == 1){
     //dsm($field);
     $field['#attributes']['required'] = 'required';
   }
  }
}
```

Put both files to a folder named `webform_formalters` and upload to your site's module folder and enable the module. See if it works.

Unlike other forms, web forms' fields are stored in $form['submitted'] array. So we go through each item (which should be an array of form definitions) and check if the element has marked as required. 
if so, we add or **merge** required attribute. We are altering an existing form, so we are not going to pop out existing attributes.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your time with this. Out of interest why can't you perform this function in template.php?

Comment: Hey @ayesh-k thanks for your help! I added this into template.php. The functionality works! But also produces this error message `Notice: Undefined index: #required in innovista_form_webform_client_form_alter() (line 188 of /home/sites/innovista.org/public_html/beta/sites/all/themes/innovista/template.php).` But only once per form.

Comment: I fixed this by wrapping your if statement within `if(isset($field['#required'])){`. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Yes it will work. But better if you put solenoid like this right into the existing if statement. if (is_array($field) && isset($field[#required]) && $field[#re ...